# Merge/Include Android Version Support

Tags: android, android-layout, merge, android-xml

I am aware this shouldn't be here, but I believe in the knowledge of the community... I just want to ask what is the lowest android version for merge/include is supported?

I have a 2.3.6 Phone, Can I have it support Merge/Include XML? Does it contribute for me not being able to run my app on the phone even though I have a MIN SDK 11 support and Target SDK 17?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.3.6 supports merge and include. You can't run your app because 2.3.6 is SDK 10 and your min is 11.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, simple things really bites!